# Does a process inherit both the logical and the physical working directories?

Tags: linux, process

I know that when a process is launched, it inherits the working directory of its parent process. But does it inherit both the logical and the physical working directories or just the physical working directory?

Comment: Only shells have such concepts. If a process never run a shell, then it just has current working directory, which is a property maintained by the kernel for every thread, and it's not a simple string.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, sort of. The "logical" working directory gets carried in the environment variable `PWD`. [`environ(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) says it's "Set by some shells", so obviously application dependent. Another issue is if the other program reads it:

```
/tmp$ ln -s ~ link  
/tmp$ cd link  
/tmp/link$ bash -c "pwd"
/tmp/link
/tmp/link$ zsh -c "pwd" 
/home/itvirta
/tmp/link$ dash -c "pwd"
/tmp/link
```

Bash and `dash` seem to count on it, `zsh` doesn't (on my system, I'm sure it's configurable).

Answer (score 1):

The [getcwd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) system call returns physical pathnames, as [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) mandates that

> The pathname shall contain no components that are dot or dot-dot, or
>   are symbolic links.

Linux appears to use a more lower-level mechanism than names to pass the CWD, as you can rename a directory while another program uses it as its CWD.